# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the name of the page from **props** match, here's the attempt below on first boot

The console does not display the call to this.props.match.path

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Post from './Post'

export default class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
      namePage: ''
   };
   componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        namePage: this.props.match.path.slice(1)[0].toUpperCase() + this.props.match.path.slice(2)
    })
  render(){
    return (
             <div>
                   <h2>{this.state.namePage}</h2>
             </div>

    )
}

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
that's what I get when starting the reaction, help me understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you post output of console.log(this.props.match.path)

Comment: try `namePage: this.props.match.path.slice(1)[0]? this.props.match.path.slice(1)[0].toUpperCase() + this.props.match.path.slice(2) : null`

Comment: @PriyeshKumar if lifecycle ComponentWillMount (this.props.match.path) = "/"

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz i have empty text after you advice ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify why you are only taking the firsts character of the path and then only that from the first array, and concatenating that with the next first character only? What kind of result are you expecting from your output?

Try removing the [0] from the slice and see if that returns what you are looking for.

Comment: in this.props.match.path i have "/posts"

Comment: Great so we see that your error was originating from the [0].  Is this the path that you are looking to get?

Comment: during the first application download  match.path equals "/"